# adding a value with jq fails if the value has spaces

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

When I try to add a bash string, that contains spaces with jq an error message will be generated. The error doesn't occur, if there are no spaces.

**the code that generates the error**

```bash
value="value with spaces"
echo {} | jq ". +={"key":"'$value'"}"
```

*error message*

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_TEXT or QQSTRING_INTERP_START or QQSTRING_END (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: . +={"key":"value             jq: 1 compile error`

*expected output*

`{"key":"value with spaces"}`

*note*
without spaces in the value bash variable, the command will run just fine

Comment: Don't inject data into code. See the [manual how to invoke](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) jq, and you'll find the `--arg` option. Use it like so: `jq -n --arg myvar "${value}" '{key: $myvar}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly format the string you are using in `jq`.

You can create the variable in the same way:

```
VAL="value with spaces"
```

And using it like this:

```
jq -n --arg myvar "${VAL}" '{key: $myvar}'
{
  "key": "value with spaces"
}
```

Comment: the main purpose of my question isn't to find a way to edit strings, but to have a general way to add data to json data. Seeing as I want to use these things in scripts, using string manipulation is highly unsuitable and a hacky workaround at best

Comment: great, i get your point. I have editted my anwser, i think now it gives you what you are looking for. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Don't inject data into code. See the [manual how to invoke](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) jq, and you'll find the `--arg` option. Use it like so: `jq -n --arg myvar "${VAL}" '{key: $myvar}'`

Comment: ouh thanks! i have added that to my answer! great!